# Lookup item by ASIN with Amazon MWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using [Amazon MWS](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html) and [XML Feeds API](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/200357600) *(unfortunately I think you need a seller account to view these links)*

I need to get a list of all the items we sell on Amazon (to cross reference product names across our other selling channels).

So technically this means I need to either :

- Get a direct list of all products in our seller marketplace (name, SKU) **OR**
- Lookup a list of ASIN numbers and get product name + SKU back. I can get a list of ASINs we sell via the Inventory feed, but it doesn't give me product name..

There doesn't seem to be any way in the MWS or XML API to do these simple tasks!!

The only way I've found to lookup an ASIN is using this API which is from the 
`Product Advertising API` of all places....

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/index.html?ItemLookup.html

It just seems really bizarre to me that I can't use the MWS (or XML API) and I'd like to know if this is the only way before I continue with the 'Product Advertising API'.

Answer (score 4):

What you really want is the equivalent of the `OpenListings` report from the `Product Advertising API` in MWS and that is the `RequestReport` call with a report type of `_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_`. This returns you all the inventory a seller has listed on Amazon and from here to getting your ASIN from that list it's close.

You can find out more details in their [documentation](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html)

Also, I advise you to not use the Product Advertising API anymore as Amazon deprecated it and it will be out of use this time next year.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the Amazon ECS Item Lookup to find products by ASIN. So you are on the right track. Amazon MWS has a lot of protential so why they do not have the one API set for everything is beyond me.